# Separate user role in SQL

Tags: sql

I have a table called `user_role_link` where the column are `userid, roleid`, `bitlive` and `bitdeleted`.
This table links to the `dbo.user_role` where in here I have columns `roleid`, `DescriptionRole`

I want to extract all the users with introleid in (256, 308, 313) but not to be part of this roles: introleid NOT  IN (225, 228, 229, 230, 231, 232, 233, 236) normally if you have on of this you could have these ones (256, 308, 313).

So what I am looking to achieve is to remove these roles from the users (256, 308, 313) where they don't have the main one (225, 228, 229, 230, 231, 232, 233, 236)
By mistake someone granted to these users the roles without having the parent one.

My query is like this

```
select distinct intuserid
from user_role_link 
where introleid in (256, 308, 313, 314, 484, 485)
  and introleid NOT  IN (225, 228, 229, 230, 231, 232, 233, 236, 237, 239, 240, 241, 242) 
  and bitLive = 1
  and bitDeleted = 0
```

Please can you let me know how this can be improved.

Comment: All those hard-coded id's look a bit strange. How do you know which id's to type?

Comment: You can skip the `NOT IN`. None of them fulfill the IN condition.

Comment: Agree with you jarlh, but that was like that just to show you what I would like to achieve. Id's are jut as a reference for you . All has been sorted with LukStorms help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So you want to remove 3 roles from users, but only when any of those other roles don't exist for them.

Then you could use a `NOT EXISTS`

```
DELETE 
FROM user_role_link ur1
WHERE roleid IN (256, 308, 313)
  AND bitLive = 1
  AND bitDeleted = 0
  AND NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT 1
    FROM user_role_link ur2
    WHERE ur2.userid = ur1.userid
      AND ur2.roleid IN (225, 228, 229, 230, 231, 232, 233, 236)
  );
```

Comment: Hi LukStorms, Really helpful your response. I haven't thought I should do it like this. It works. Thank you a lot.